# Unable to write in Windows Run prompt through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, awtrobot

I need to access one shared path through selenium Webdriver but I am unable to write that shared path `"\\18.187.980.12\\Logs\\abc.log"` in Windows Run prompt through Selenium.
I am using Robot classes to open run prompt

```
    Robot robot = new Robot();  // Robot class throws AWT Exception  
    Thread.sleep(2000); 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);  
    Thread.sleep(2000);
```

This code is opening run prompt but I am unable to write the shared path `"\\18.187.980.12\\Logs\\abc.log"` in run prompt.
Please suggest next step.
My new Code is given below:

```
  package ForNewFramework;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

class RobotClass {

    Robot robot = new Robot(); // Robot class throws AWT Exception

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException,
            InterruptedException {
        // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        new RobotClass();
    }

    public RobotClass() throws AWTException {

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); // press arrow down key of keyboard
                                                // to navigate and select Save
                                                // radio button
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R); // press arrow down key of keyboard to
                                        // navigate and select Save radio button
        type("Prateek");

    }

    private void type(String s) {
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
        for (byte b : bytes) {
            int code = b;
            // keycode only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
            if (code > 96 && code < 123)
                code = code - 32;
            robot.delay(40);
            robot.keyPress(code);
            robot.keyRelease(code);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why have you put type prateek in a catch block ?

Comment: Please put   type("Prateek"); inside a try block .. otherwise it will neve execute.

Comment: Let me know if you still see an issue

Comment: Still facing same issue....

Comment: Put your updates code.. Need to see it and also what is happening exactly. Thanks

Comment: I had updated the code in question.

Comment: Ok i found your error.. give me sometime i will write the correct code

Comment: Please check i have written the complete code you need

Comment: Awesome.... Nailed it. This code is running perfectly (y) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well at the end of the day all strings are result of key presses so you can press the key in keyboard by passing the correct ASCII value (key code).

Please find the entire code that you need:

```
package ForNewFramework;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

class RobotClass {

    Robot robot = new Robot(); // Robot class throws AWT Exception

    public static void main(String[] args) throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
        // WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        new RobotClass().runWindows("\\\\18.187.980.12\\\\Logs\\\\abc.log");
    }


    public RobotClass() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {

    }

    public void runWindows(String run) throws InterruptedException{

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS); // press arrow down key of keyboard
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R); // press arrow down key of keyboard to
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
        type(run);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    }

    private void type(String s) throws InterruptedException  {
        Thread.sleep(2000); 
        byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
        for (byte b : bytes)
        {
          int code = b;
          // keycode only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
          if (code >=65 && code<=90){
              System.out.println(code);
              robot.delay(1000);
              robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT );

              robot.keyPress(code);
              robot.keyRelease(code);
              robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);


          }else if (code > 96 && code < 123) {
              code = code - 32;
              System.out.println(code);
              robot.delay(2000);
              robot.keyPress(code);
              robot.keyRelease(code);
          }
          else{
              robot.delay(2000);
              robot.keyPress(code);
              robot.keyRelease(code);
          }

        }
}
}
```

This code tries to open that directory and works perfectly, I have tested it.

It took some time to figure out what was going wrong. You didn't release the keys, that's why it was not working for you and also you had to handle the different key codes that might come. This robot class only writes A-Z.

Here is a list of key events which might come handy - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/KeyEvent.html#VK_R

Comment: Hi,
I tried it but It is not writing anything inside Windows Run propmt like 
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
type("Prateek");

Comment: show your code and explain what you exactly tried. You can edit the questions

Comment: Hi,
I tried it but It is not writing anything inside Windows Run propmt like: 
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
type("Prateek");

I am calling this methoed in class
       private void type(String s)
       {
         byte[] bytes = s.getBytes();
         for (byte b : bytes)
         {
           int code = b;
           // keycode only handles [A-Z] (which is ASCII decimal [65-90])
           if (code > 96 && code < 123) code = code - 32;
           robot.delay(40);
           robot.keyPress(code);
           robot.keyRelease(code);
         }
       }

Comment: I had removed all the try catch, thread.sleep but Still i am facing same problem

Comment: Great .. happy to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use sendkey stock of selenium class

```
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.TAB).perform()
```

if you want to use robot class than It should be something like this

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='User Name:']/following::div/input")).sendKeys("UserName");

Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_WINDOWS);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_R)
```

Comment: I am using the same but after this , i am unable to write anything inside windows Run propmt